# File InputStream is throwing Exception I cannot play the mp3 files from my external storage

Tags: android, android-studio, local-storage, android-permissions, fileinputstream

I have my 50k mp3 files in a folder and I place the folder in my external storage and now I am trying to play the mp3 file by its name from my external storage path but after the File Inputstream my code is moving to catch exception. Here is my code

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState()
                        .equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                    String filePath = File.separator + "sdcard" + File.separator + "Android" + File.separator + "media" + File.separator + "convertMp3ToDb" + File.separator + "ldoce6_hwd_gb" + File.separator + fileName;
                    try {
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                        String zipFileName = "convertMp3ToDb" + File.separator + "ldoce6_hwd_gb" + File.separator + fileName;
                        String entry = null;
                        while ((entry = fis.toString()) != null) {
                            if (entry.toString().endsWith(zipFileName)) {
                                File Mytemp = File.createTempFile("TCL", "mp3", getActivity().getCacheDir());
                                Mytemp.deleteOnExit();
                                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(Mytemp);
                                for (int c = fis.read(); c != -1; c = fis.read()) {
                                    try {
                                        fos.write(c);
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                                fos.close();
                                FileInputStream MyFile = new FileInputStream(Mytemp);
                                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(MyFile.getFD());
                                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                                mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
                            }
                        }
                        fis.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    } finally {
                        if (mediaPlayer != null && !mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            mediaPlayer.stop();
                            mediaPlayer = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What exception getting?

Comment: `while ((entry = fis.toString()) != null)`. You realise what fis.toString() returns? You realise that the while loop will continue forever? Why are you copying the file first?

Comment: I want to play mp3 files from my device storage location path, I am unable to check what my while loop returns because before entering the while loop i am getting the IOException